# How to ignore blanks in Excel while calculating Average and vlookup

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate averages for students using Vlookup in excel. I am using the following formula or calculation

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(BG79,$T$9:$AJ$2544,{9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},0),""))
```

But it is taking blanks as 0 and calculating the numbers.

Need help to ignore blanks and only calculate populated numbers.

Comment: So why not re-write the formula with sum() and count the numbers greater than zero, then divide?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I used Sumproduct which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the formula to AVERAGEIF, This will work for both blank and zeros

```
=AVERAGEIF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(BG79,$T$9:$AJ$2544,{9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},0),""),"<>0")
```

Simple Example
[image: AVERAGEIF SAMPLE]